# Pass variable from form to function

Tags: php, mysql

I have this in my profile controller

```
public function search()
{
        $searchString=htmlentities(Request::post('search_field'));
        $this->View->render('profile/search', array(
        'user' => UserModel::searchProfile($searchString)
        ));

}
```

And this in my model

```
    public static function searchProfile($searchString)
{
    if(empty($searchString)){
    Session::add('feedback_negative', Text::get('FEEDBACK_UNKNOWN_ERROR'));
    return false;
        }
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
    $query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name LIKE :query");
    $query->execute(array(':query' => '%'.$searchString.'%'));

    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

But the redirect system is not working with this (hitting refresh brings up "would you like to send again?")

But, if i send `$searchString` in search() it works (and the URL looks cool).

But if search($searchString) is empty ($searchString = null, empty input field) I get an error:`Warning: Missing argument 1 for ProfileController::search()` and ofc: `Notice: Undefined variable: searchString`

How do I get `Request::post('search_field')` into `search()`?

Comment: You might tag this with whatever framework you're using.

Comment: What framework are you using, it's probably generating URI in a RESTful manner

Comment: @AbraCadaver I'm using panique/huge framework (its on github), couldn't fint a tag for it.

Comment: @MichaelVilleneuve see prev answer, and i tried to google RESTful and it might be that the framework is using this design.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the way to go but i solved it like this:

```
public function search($searchString='')
{
        $this->View->render('profile/search', array(
        'user' => UserModel::searchProfile(htmlentities($searchString))
        ));

}
```

and this for the form:

```
onsubmit="window.location = '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>profile/search/' + search_field.value; return false;"
```

So the search query will send to http://example.com/profile/search/query

Any security risk?